# Writing autosys job information to Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, autosys

Here's my situation: we have no access to the autosys server other than using the autorep command. We need to keep detailed statistics on each of our jobs. I have written some Oracle database tables that will store start/end times, exit codes, JIL, etc.

What I need to know is what is the easiest way to output the data we require (which is all available in the autosys tables that we do not have access to) to an Oracle database.

Here are the technical details of our system:
autosys version - I cannot figure out how to get this information
Oracle version - 11g
We have two separate environments - one for UAT/QA/IT and several PROD servers

Comment: So say for a job job1, you need all these details and want to store in a table in row format. Like jobname, start time,end time,jil definition etc. How  do you want to insert the records in the table? What about jobs which run multiple times a day? Give an example and I can suggest you a way.

Comment: Also I assume you are running autosys on unix server

Comment: So to answer the implied question, yes we want to capture all details possible although most of them will remain static for the most part (JIL description and jobname for instance). 

I am expecting to have to use SQLloader to get the information into our Oracle DB, but I am not certain that is the correct way to handle this.

Most of our jobs only run once per day. The only reason it would run more than once would be in the case of a job failure, we would fix the issue and kick off the job again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like below

1. Create a table with the parameters you want to put. Put a key columns which should be auto generated. The jil column should be able to handle huge data. Also add one columns for sysdate.
2. Create a shell script. Inside it do as follows
3. "autorep -j  -l0" to get all the jobs you want and put them in a file. -l0 is to ignore duplicate jobs. If a Box contain a job, then without -l0 you will get the job twice.
4. create a loop and read all the job names one by one.
5. In the loop, set varaibles for jobname/starttime/endtime/status (which all you can get from autorep -j . Then use a variable to hold jil by autorep -q -j
6. Append all these variable values in a flat file.
7. End the loop. After exiting a loop you wil end up with a file with all the job details.
8. Then use SQL loader to put the data in your oracle table. You can hardcode a control file and use it for every run. But the content of data file will change for every run.

Let me know if any part is not clear.

Comment: Thank you! I believe you've given me the proper direction. One question though. Step 3 mentions using "autorep -j -10" - is that a "one zero" or is that "capital I zero"? I tried using "autorep -j <job name> -10" command but received the error "CAUAJM_E_40003 Invalid parameters specified."

Comment: it is small l and zero.

Comment: Again, I thank you. Our version of autosys is not allowing me to use the lower case I option, however there is nothing prohibiting me from removing duplicates from the flat file once the script is completed. I greatly appreciate the direction you've given me.